# Flutter Animation on Android: D/skia (22985): Could not invert viewmatrix

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

### Steps to Reproduce

Without going too deep in the code, I have an animation triggered every time the time changes, where:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (this._currentTime != widget.amountOfTime) {
      this._changeTimeAnimation();
    }

    return new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: this._animation,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) => this._flipAnimation(child),
      child: new Text(
        this._currentTime,
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 100.0),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And *this._flipAnimation()* is the following:

```
Transform _flipAnimation(Widget child) {
    /// Function used to generate a flip animation for the time

    final Matrix4 transform = new Matrix4.identity()
      ..scale(1.0, this._animation.value, 1.0);

    return Transform(
      transform: transform,
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      child: child,
    );
  }
```

Every time the animation is triggered, I get the message `D/skia    (22985): Could not invert viewmatrix`. Why is that?

I will note, the animation appears to be working just fine on the device, but that printout is odd.

### Logs

After `flutter run`:

```
Performing full restart...
Restarted app in 2,182ms.
D/skia    (22985): Could not invert viewmatrix
D/skia    (22985): Could not invert viewmatrix
D/skia    (22985): Could not invert viewmatrix
D/skia    (22985): Could not invert viewmatrix
D/skia    (22985): Could not invert viewmatrix
```

### Flutter Doctor

After running `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.2.8, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E199, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.2.8 at /Users/jvanderen11/flutter
    • Framework revision b397406561 (13 days ago), 2018-04-02 13:53:20 -0700
    • Engine revision c903c217a1
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.43.0.flutter-52afcba357

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jvanderen11/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Developer Tools/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.3, Build version 9E145
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Developer Tools/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/jvanderen11/Applications/JetBrains Toolbox/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.app
    • Flutter plugin version 23.1.3
    • Dart plugin version 181.4203.498

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Does the error happen as soon as the animation starts or at some point during it (like half way maybe)?

Comment: It appears to happen as soon as the widget is built from it's parent (i.e. Center (child: ListTimeWidget(timeUnit: timeUnit))

Comment: Hmmm. Does it only happen once per animation? Not clear from your log if that's multiple animations or just the one. I'm wondering if maybe it's something to do with scaling 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 as I believe that results in an invalid matrix (see [this](https://github.com/Igalia/skia/blob/master/src/gpu/GrAAConvexPathRenderer.cpp#L733) and [this](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/master/src/core/SkMatrix44.cpp#L502)).
As a workaround could you try `..scale(1.0, this._animation.value + 1e-100, 1.0)` as that might avoid the multiply-by-zero without affecting it otherwise.

Comment: Great suggestion! Android still throws an error on `1e-100`, but it does like `0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`

Comment: okay haha probably the conversion from a dart double to a c++ float/double (whatever they use in the underlying Skia library). Glad I could be of service, I'll add it as an answer as we're not really supposed to answer in comments =)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I accidentally posted a number with too many 0's, but I adjusted the answer to reflect this :-)

Comment: Okay =) I was wondering if it was maybe something to do with 1.75494351e-38 which is the smallest positive float value

Comment: That could very well be. Interesting how significant small numbers can be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that when the scaling is at (1.0, 0.0, 1.0), it results in a matrix Skia doesn't like (probably not valid - see [where skia generates the error](https://github.com/Igalia/skia/blob/master/src/gpu/GrAAConvexPathRenderer.cpp#L733), and what I think is [the line where it causes the error](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/master/src/core/SkMatrix44.cpp#L502)).

A simple fix is to make sure you never actually pass scale(1.0, 0.0, 1.0), either through modifying your code, or adding a very small amount to the number each time i.e. `..scale(1.0, this._animation.value + smallval, 1.0)`

Apparently `smallval=1e-100` is too small as it gets lost in the conversion to c++ for skia, but `smallval=0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` does work.